# Linear Alegbra - Is $T$ diagonalize?

Tags: linear-algebra

The characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^4$ and $T(1,0,0,0)=(1,1,2,1)$ is T diagonalize?

I don't have any idea how to approach this, Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $1$. Now, if $T$ were diagonalizable, then $T$ would have to be equal to $I$ (prove it-it's simple).

But $T(1,0,0,0) \neq(1,0,0,0)$. So, $T \neq I$, and hence $T$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: T must be equal to I since T is similar to a matrix with $diag(1,1,1,1)$?

Comment: @JaVaPG: Yes- that's the reason.